# Moving physical drive (SSD) with installed Ubuntu from one machine to another

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I haven't found exact answer to my question, so I'm creating this thread. Most of the threads considered transferring data - not moving physical drive.

I'm using laptop with installed Ubuntu. I'm going to buy a new laptop and I want to put SSD from my old laptop to the new laptop.

Can I move physical drive (SSD) with installed Ubuntu from one machine to another and still have working system?

Will it work correctly or I have to format disk and install system again from the scratch?

I'm asking this question, because I'd be happy if I could avoid next procedure of re-installing and configuring my system from the scratch, when I have it done on the old machine. It can be fun, but takes some time.

Comment: I have moved an SSD from one desktop to another and it worked fine so you should be ok to do so.

Comment: Issues may be video driver. If same video system then a lot easier. Sometimes other drivers like Ethernet or wireless may be different, also.

Comment: Related info on [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Migrate_installation_to_new_hardware), [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/moving-linux-install-to-a-new-computer) and [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/q/52314/407820).

Comment: When I did this I only had to fight with the new Network card but I was on a the server ver. 16.04, the system crested a different interfaces file and I was a little confused since I was modifying the file and it wasn't taking the network changes not even after rebooting but everything else worked, as long as you are on the same processing architecture and brand it should work

Comment: Help my be found: [quora](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-move-my-existing-Linux-hard-drive-to-another-PC-and-it-will-boot-and-run-perfectly-without-the-need-to-reinstall-everything) or [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368516/unable-to-boot-after-moving-hard-drive-to-another-computer)

Answer (score 6):

I moved an SSD with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS from a broken Lenovo Ideapad Y560 with ATI GPU to a Desktop PC with intel integrated graphics and it booted perfectly. Foremore, it detected new graphics card and install intel sandy drivers automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically if you haven't adapted your kernel and stayed on the generic one and your ubuntu wasn't an old one, I assume you can try to go ahead. Post your success experience later here.

Comment: Actually, I had some problem with my system and decided to format disk and install clean system, so I haven't opportunity to check this out.

Answer (score 3):

I was working on my laptop when my new one arrived. I shut my old one down, took out the drive and installed the drive in the new computer, turned it on and continued working :)

Mileage may vary, but I think as @Laket said, if you haven't messed with the kernel, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I moved an SSD with Ubuntu 16.04 from an Intel NUC DN2820FYKH to a Gigabyte Brix BXBT-1900 (both barebones mini-PCs) and it wouldn't boot. I couldn't find a quick fix other than reinstalling the OS. So don't assume it will just work. Moving the SSD to another DN2820FYKH worked flawlessly (obviously).